# "Use Database" command inside a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I would like to dynamically use a database inside a stored procedure but the `use database_name`  command is not supported inside procedures.

What alternatives are there?

Answer (score 3):

From [MySQL Documentation on Stored Routine Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-routines-syntax.html)  When the routine is invoked, an implicit USE db_name is performed (and undone when the routine terminates).
**USE statements within stored routines are not permitted**

If you need to query tables from other databases you can do it like **DBName.TableName.** and you can change DBName dynamically.